# Solidity confused question in official example

Tags: solidity

I am new to Solidity and reading Solidity's officail example: [BlindAuction](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/solidity-by-example.html#id2). Some detail is confusing.

According to

```
            if (bidToCheck.blindedBid != keccak256(abi.encodePacked(value, fake, secret))) {
                // Bid was not actually revealed.
                // Do not refund deposit.
                continue;
            }
```

the `uint value` in the reveal process should be exactly the same as `value` send to Contract in the bid process, so why do we need to write

```
            if (!fake && bidToCheck.deposit >= value) {
```

instead of

```
            if (!fake) {
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two API (external) functions:

1. `function bid(...) payable`, via which the user sends ether to the contract
2. `function reveal(...)`, via which the user reveals his/her bid

The documentation says:

> The bid is valid if the ether sent together with the bid is at least "value"

Function `bid` stores an indication of the amount of ether sent to the contract (`msg.value`).

Function `reveal` needs to verify that the user bid is **at least that value**.